# Symfony DBAL insert gives: "Syntax error or access violation: 1064"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, dbal

I'm trying to insert some data into database, but something is off here. Cannot catch what it is and I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me what's going on with this one.

My table looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name`.`order` (
  `orderID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_ordernumber` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `order_orderweight` INT NOT NULL,
  ... And other columns as well, but all NULL
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I'm using Symfony2-framework and it's DBAL-insert here:

```
$conn->insert('order', array(
              'order_ordernumber' => $this->orderid,
              'order_orderweight' => $this->totalweight
             ));
```

"$this->orderid" is string variable, and "$this->totalweight" is int.

And it gives this error-message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO order (order_ordernumber, order_orderweight) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["000001", 900]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_ordernumber, order_orderweight) VALUES ('000001', '900')' at line 1
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception: PDOException »
```

I can do the same query on pure sql and it works, this one doesn't. What on earth is going on with this one?

Comment: `order` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, you should prefix your table to prevent such error.

Comment: How come pure sql works if this is about reserved keywords?

Comment: You need to espace reserved word `order` with backticks `>insert('order'`

Comment: You can do it in pure SQL with backquotes arround the "order" word, or with the database name prefixing the table name. Otherwise it's not possible, it's a reserved keyword : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Oooooh that's right.. I do have those backquotes around the order-word.. Guess I'm a bit tired already.. :D

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié, if you could give your answer as answer and not comment, I'd select it as a correct answer.  Thank you all for helping a tired coder in trouble. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order` is a reserved keyword in MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

You have to use backquotes arround the word to prevent this error. But a better recommendation would be to prefix your table.